# How to write an emacs mode for a new language?

Tags: emacs, mode

I would like to write an **Emacs major mode** for a 4GL.
Can someone show me a tutorial?
As far as I googled I was able to find only this broken:

link http://two-wugs.net/emacs/mode-tutorial.html

Comment: What would be *really* nice would be to have a language mode generator from a syntax specification written in BNFC. Is there any work in this area?

Answer (score 23):

If you're lazy, one easy way is to extend `generic-mode` to know about your new language:

http://emacswiki.org/emacs/GenericMode

I do this a lot for config files for applications that I work with a lot to get decent syntax highlighting.  [Here's one](http://lists.digium.com/pipermail/asterisk-dev/attachments/20050113/a1304cae/asterisk-mode.obj) I did for the asterisk PBX a long time ago as an example.