# Emacs Lisp syntax highlighting

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, elisp, syntax-rules

I want to write a syntax highlighting extension for Emacs, but I Googling of variations on "emacs syntax highlight tutorial" have all failed. How do I go about learning how to write an Emacs highlighter? What good resources are there for learning how to do such things?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're looking in the wrong place.  Look at "[font-lock-mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Font-Lock.html)".

Comment: This looks awesome. I will definitely investigate this further when it's not 1:40 in the morning.

Answer (score 5):

There's [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756666/match-regular-expression-as-keyword-in-define-generic-mode/756927), on how to define a major mode with syntax highlighting using `'define-generic-mode`.  The question focuses on figuring out how to get the syntax highlighting working.

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately you were searching for the wrong terms, "syntax highlighting" is not emacs vocabulary :). You should have searched for something like "write emacs mode".

There was already a question for this: "[How to write an emacs mode for a new language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91201/how-to-write-an-emacs-mode-for-a-new-language)" with some good pointers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in writing your own highlighting, [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875543/how-can-i-color-certain-things-in-emacs/) covered this and may be of value to you.  It included this code snippet:

```
(defun django-highlight-comments ()
  (interactive "p")
  (highlight-regexp "{%.*?%}" 'hi-orange))
(add-hook 'html-mode-hook 'django-highlight-comments)
```

Code courtesy of [Ashutosh Mehra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73653/ashutosh-mehra)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875543/how-can-i-color-certain-things-in-emacs/875628#875628).

Answer (score 0):

http://a-kat.com/Emacs_Major_Modes.html