# Simplest Emacs syntax highlighting tutorial?

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs23, xemacs

I would like to create only a syntax highlighting minor mode for Emacs.  I have the "Writing GNU Emacs Extensions" by O'Reilly, but it does not go into any depth of detail.  Is there a simple tutorial for a real or fake programming language highlighting mode?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write an emacs mode for a new language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91201/how-to-write-an-emacs-mode-for-a-new-language)

Comment: @dmckee: I don't think this is a duplicate of that question. It is true that some of the *answers* there cover this subject somewhat. You would be better off linking to whatever you think answers this question, rather than signaling that this *question* duplicates the major-mode *question*.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Defining a custom [Generic Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GenericMode) is probably the best place to start.  You can define basic syntax highlighting for a language as simply as the following snippet.

```
(require 'generic-x)

(define-generic-mode 
  'my-mode                          ;; name of the mode
  '("//")                           ;; comments delimiter
  '("function" "var" "return")      ;; some keywords
  '(("=" . 'font-lock-operator) 
    ("+" . 'font-lock-operator)     ;; some operators
    (";" . 'font-lock-builtin))     ;; a built-in 
  '("\\.myext$")                    ;; files that trigger this mode
   nil                              ;; any other functions to call
  "My custom highlighting mode"     ;; doc string
)
```

It's great for quickly defining some basic syntax highlighting for obscure languages.  I even use it for log files in some cases.

Comment: would one save this is a file like my-syntax.el and add something like `(require 'my-syntax)` in .emacs? Thank you

Comment: You can do that, or put it directly in your .emacs if you prefer.  If you put it in a seperate file, ensure it is in your load-path and that you include the line (provide 'my-syntax) at the end if you want to use (require 'my-syntax).

Comment: @ColinCochrane how do you use it for log files?

Answer (score 5):

EmacsWiki's [Mode tutorial](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeTutorial) has a little more information on creating a major mode, in case you want to expand from syntax highlighting only.

Answer (score 3):

You also might find it useful to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367611/emacs-highlighting-todo-only-in-comments/3900056#3900056), which has a pointer to code that defines a minor mode to highlight certain key words - but only in strings and comments.

A minor mode is nicer if all you want is highlights - less baggage.

The relevant portions of the manual are for  the function [`'font-lock-add-keywords`](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Customizing-Keywords.html#Customizing-Keywords) and the variable [`font-lock-keywords`](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html#Search_002dbased-Fontification).