# In emacs, matching do and endo statements

Tags: emacs, emacs23

Greetings,

I am reviewing some code in the Gauss programming language. In it, loops can begin with do and end with endo? How do I see which endo matches which do. I want to see an outline of the structure of the code. What would be really cool is to highlight in different colors different blocks of code (e.g. main loop in blue, nested loop in yellow, loop nested inside that in green, etc).

a) How can I figure out the matching do/endo pairs?
b) Is the color highlighting I described possible?

Answer (score 3):

Your description of what you want sounds like you need a major mode for the language.  There is a full section [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeTutorial) at EamcsWiki.  Also, there was another discussion on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91201/how-to-write-an-emacs-mode-for-a-new-language) about creating major mode.  You could write a mode for suiting your needs, or, making the work easier, [here](http://www.econ.yale.edu/~steveb/gauss-mode.el) is a gauss mode for Emacs :).