# How to write an emacs major-mode like dired

Tags: emacs, elisp, major-mode

I've found a bunch of information ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91201/how-to-write-an-emacs-mode-for-a-new-language)) on writing a major-mode for a language, but... I'd like to write a mode along the lines of `dired` or `tetris` - modes that use the buffer as a GUI.

In the ["Major Modes" section of the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Major-Modes.html#Major-Modes), the "Basic Major Modes" page implies it should base the mode on `special-mode`, but I couldn't find any more useful information

Is there any good tutorials on writing a `special-mode` derived mode? Any good basic "hello world"-level examples of such a thing?

Comment: Looking for the same exact thing - happened across the same page in the manual advising deriving such modes from special-mode, but I haven't been able to find anything useful. Bereft of any intentional guidance, I had vaguely planned to follow what [magit](http://philjackson.github.com/magit/) and [browse-kill-ring](https://github.com/browse-kill-ring/browse-kill-ring) are doing...

Comment: The O'Reilly book ["Writing GNU Emacs Extensions"](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565922617.do) has examples of writing several major modes, one of which is a crossword game mode.. Parts are on Google Books - I don't particularly like how the code is presented (chunks of completed code that all magically works together in the end, rather than a working example that is improved upon), and is pretty old (1997).. but I'll have a look

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on `undo-tree-visualizer-mode` in [UndoTree](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UndoTree).

It's pretty small and is not based on a language.

Answer (score 1):

Zachary Kanfer once gave a talk titled **Writing Games with Emacs**, where he live-coded a simple `tictactoe-mode`. You can find it on YouTube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gk39mp8Vy4M), and he uploaded his code [here](https://zck.me/tictactoe/tictactoe.el).

I found it a great introduction to writing my own special mode.